# Squid 3.5.4: ssl bump: error - Error negotiating SSL connection on FD 10: Success (0)

Tags: proxy, ssl-certificate, https, squid, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to install squid 3.5.4 (on docker, running debian 8) and run it in ssl-bump mode.
Compilation:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/squid --srcdir=. --disable-maintainer-mode \
--disable-dependency-tracking --disable-silent-rules --enable-inline\
--disable-arch-native --enable-async-io=8 \
--enable-storeio=ufs,aufs,diskd,rock \
--enable-removal-policies=lru,heap --enable-delay-pools \
--enable-cache-digests --enable-icap-client \
--enable-follow-x-forwarded-for \
--enable-auth-basic=DB,fake,getpwnam,LDAP,MSNT-multi-domain,NCSA,NIS,PAM,POP3,RADIUS,SASL,SMB \
--enable-auth-digest=file,LDAP \
--enable-auth-negotiate=kerberos,wrapper \
--enable-auth-ntlm=fake,smb_lm \
--enable-external-acl-helpers=file_userip,kerberos_ldap_group,LDAP_group,session,SQL_session,unix_group,wbinfo_group \
--enable-url-rewrite-helpers=fake --enable-eui \
 --enable-esi --enable-icmp --enable-zph-qos \
--disable-translation --with-filedescriptors=65536 \
--with-large-files --with-default-user=squid \
--enable-linux-netfilter \
CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIE -Wall" LDFLAGS="-fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now" CPPFLAGS="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" \
CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIE " --enable-ssl --with-openssl --enable-ssl-crtd
```

Changed configuration (squid.conf) (rest is default):

```
# Squid normally listens to port 3128 \
http_port 9090
sslcrtd_program /opt/squid/libexec/ssl_crtd -s /opt/squid/var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB
https_port 8080 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB key=/opt/squid/certs/private.pem cert=/opt/squid/certs/public.pem

### New configuration for Squid version 3.5
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all
### New config ends
sslproxy_capath /etc/ssl/certs
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
always_direct allow all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER
```

Generated certificates:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout private.pem -out public.pem
```

Generate squid certs dir and change ownership:

```
/opt/squid/libexec/ssl_crtd -c -s /opt/squid/var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB
chown -R squid:squid /opt/squid/var/lib/ssl_db
```

CA Root certs are present in the default path

```
squid@525f5d9c759a:/opt/squid/certs$ ls -lsthr  /etc/ssl/certs | wc -l
741
```

I am testing this configuration, using HTTP CONNECT, configuring the proxy directly in the browser.

> ISSUE:

I get the following error when the browser request hits the proxy

```
8zjv9ksCWknblqfZ3rjWczvKNRboHpu940olZAbvSP0JWSXhFfRRTIsHIHD2/rt/
n5/qsURq/WLodLffFxuk+bLVTDZu
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

2015/05/04 15:13:46.468 kid1| client_side.cc(3981) sslCrtdHandleReply: Certificate for 172.17.0.7 was successfully recieved from ssl_crtd
2015/05/04 15:13:46.468 kid1| client_side.cc(3664) httpsCreate: will negotate SSL on local=172.17.0.7:2222 remote=172.17.42.1:40686 FD 10 flags=33
2015/05/04 15:13:46.468 kid1| AsyncCall.cc(26) AsyncCall: The AsyncCall ConnStateData::requestTimeout constructed, this=0x7f0357a16c10 [call105]
```

***2015/05/04 15:13:46.468 kid1| Error negotiating SSL connection on FD 10: Success (0)***

```
2015/05/04 15:13:46.468 kid1| AsyncCall.cc(93) ScheduleCall: comm.cc(730) will call ConnStateData::connStateClosed(FD -1, data=0x7f03575d43b8) [call95]
2015/05/04 15:13:46.468 kid1| AsyncCallQueue.cc(55) fireNext: entering ConnStateData::connStateClosed(FD -1, data=0x7f03575d43b8)
2015/05/04 15:13:46.468 kid1| AsyncCall.cc(38) make: make call ConnStateData::connStateClosed [call95]
2015/05/05 10:00:25| pinger: Initialising ICMP pinger ...
2015/05/05 10:00:25|  icmp_sock: (1) Operation not permitted
2015/05/05 10:00:25| pinger: Unable to start ICMP pinger.
2015/05/05 10:00:25|  icmp_sock: (1) Operation not permitted
2015/05/05 10:00:25| pinger: Unable to start ICMPv6 pinger.
2015/05/05 10:00:25| FATAL: pinger: Unable to open any ICMP sockets.
```

Sending a curl request shows this:

```
curl --proxy https://localhost:8080 -w '\n' https://google.com -v
* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to google.com:443
> CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.42.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
* Proxy CONNECT aborted
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

curl: (56) Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: remove the --enable-ssl option.